# Keeping the width and/or the text alignment in a HTML table after display=none

Tags: html, css

As you can see here

https://jsfiddle.net/tjvn2mLx/1/

I have a table with two cells. The last one is right-aligned.
**It works.**

I need to hide it, and then show it again.
I set style.display = 'none', **it works, it's invisible**

```
document.getElementById('table1').style.display='none'
```

I try to show it again

```
document.getElementById('table1').style.display='block'
```

and something is wrong, either the width=100% is changed or the right-align is lost.
I tried setting the display to "inline-block" too, to no avail.
Since the project is bootstrap-based, I tried with row/col too but the behavior is exactly the same. Anyway, I would like to use the table solution if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only do this change:

```
alert('now is ok')
document.getElementById('table1').style.display='none'
document.getElementById('table1').style.display='table' //here
```

https://jsfiddle.net/arman1373/kLqhfb57/1/

Comment: Perfect! The only thing, I had to add .style.width='100%' because it seems like it's "losing" it when resetting it to be a table

Comment: @ZioBit . Thankful you. But style.display='none' for is what? because without it works, also. as Aditya deleted that.

Comment: It was just to show "what I was doing". I had my table shown, then hidden (with 'none'), then shown again. I didn't know you could use 'table' too as a display type

Answer (score 1):

You should use visibility instead of display to hide like so
`visibility: hidden;`

and to show use
`visibility: visible;`

See the **fiddle here**: https://jsfiddle.net/adityasinghskit/fd4h6z5q/1/

To make it not take space add
`position: absolute;`
See the **fiddle here**: https://jsfiddle.net/adityasinghskit/fd4h6z5q/4/

Comment: Thank you. Visibility still takes the space though. I would really like to hide it all.

Comment: Then why not add **position: absolute**

Comment: Your second link in the finishing output is empty!